# What's the name of this small connector?

Tags: pcb, connector, identification, camera

I would like to know what's the name of the connector on the side of the PCB? It's really small. Width: ~ 5 mm. Height: ~ 1.2 mm.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A short name would be an IDC connector, here's a whole list of them: 
http://www.jst.com/home21.html

This one looks close to what you want:

http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/detail_e.php?series=246

Just measure the pitch (pin to pin spacing) and you should be able to find a mate.  If I remember right, finding those in the US at that pitch and in 1-100 unit volumes was a pain.  JST was eventually the guys who had what I was looking for though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Really useful (you got the right connector)